# C++ writing to file does not work?

Tags: c++, macos, file, io, ofstream

I am currently working on an iPhone game which sends a sound file over TCP to a server program. The TCP transfer works well (I've cout'ed the buffer to check if it matches the sound file, which it does). The problem is... I want to write the sound file in its own folder on the server. Each game has its unique gameID, and the gameID is supposed to be the folder's name on the server.

My write-to-file function currently looks like this:

```
void PacketInterpreter::makeFile(int gameID, std::string buffer){
    std::string gameIDdir = "mkdir " + std::to_string(gameID);
    std::system(gameIDdir.c_str());
    std::string constructedPath = std::to_string(gameID);
    constructedPath += "/";

    std::ofstream thisFile;
    thisFile.open(constructedPath+"sound.caf");
    thisFile << buffer;
    thisFile.close();

    std::cout << "File assembled at " << constructedPath << "sound.caf" << std::endl;
}
```

Everything seems to be working well -- the buffer contains the file data, the function prints the last sentence, and the function returns. The only error is... When I look for the file in the constructed directory it's not there.

What am I doing wrong? The operating system is OSX 10.9 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check `thisfile`'s state after opening? May be you need some additional `ios::openmode` flags.

Comment: You're not checking for errors at any point.

Comment: For a start, you haven't checked the result of the `std::system` call to see whether the function succeeded.  Is `mkdir` in your path?  Have you tried `/usr/bin/mkdir`?  Have you searched your whole file system to see whether the directory was created?  Do you have write permissions on the current working directory?

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory? Does your process have write privileges?

Comment: If your file path has any spaces, `mkdir` could happily make different directories than you expect.  For example, `mkdir /path/to/something with spaces/foo` would make the directories `/path/to/something`, `with` and `spaces/foo`, potentially.  (Although, without the `-p` argument, it's likely to fail at `spaces/foo` in this example.)  Really, you should test for a directory's existence, and call `mkdir` yourself, rather than calling `system()` to do it for you.  In any case, you should check for success, whether you call `mkdir` indirectly via `system()` or you call it directly yourself.